# Make table with td collapse an borders

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-5

Can I make a table like the image attached below?

The functionality I want but have trouble implementing is styling. More specifically the rounded edges and border when the row is collapsed and not.

This is what I have tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr:not(.header)').hide();
  
    $('tr.header').click(function() {
      $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
        return value == '^' ? 'v' : '^'
      });
      
      $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function() {});
    });
  });
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center overflow-scroll">
        <table class="table table-md" id="table" style="width:65%">
          <thead>
            <tr class="header">
              <th width="10%">NUM</th>
              <th>ITEM</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th width="20%">INFO</th>
              <th width="10%">INCLUDE</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr class="header">
            <th>010</th>
            <th colspan="3">Shoes</th>
            <th><span>v</span></th>
            <th><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DRAG</td>
            <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td>ITEM</td>
            <td>PREFERED</td>
            <td>EDIT</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

I am using `bootstrap-5`
[image: Example illustration]
Any helps is greatly appreciated

Comment: It would help, if you would please edit your answer and use the snippet tool `<>`.  Then others can visually see what the problem is.  And they are able to fix it as well.

Comment: Done. Click the second row for the collapse function.

Comment: That's a good start, I have upvoted it.  However, there is one more issue.  The protocol is to ask one question at a time.  You are asking 3.  The community bot may flag it.

Comment: Ok, I will make it more unilateral